# Jensen's Formula and the measure of $\{\theta \in [0, 2\pi]: f(e^{i\theta}) = 0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathbb{D} = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| < 1\}$. Suppose $f$ is continuous on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ and analytic on $\mathbb{D}$ with $f(0) \neq 0$. Then if $r$ is such that $0 < r < 1$ and $\min_{|z| = r}|f(z)| > 0$, by Jensen's Formula $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\log |f(re^{i\theta})|\, d\theta \geq \log |f(0)|.$$

The problem I am working on is to show that the set $\{\theta \in [0, 2\pi]: f(e^{i\theta}) = 0\}$ has (Lebesgue) measure 0.

I would like to do the following: Since zeros of $f$ isolated, we can choose an increasing sequence $\{r_{j}\}$ such that $r_{j} \rightarrow 1$ and $\min_{|z| = r_{j}}|f(z)| > 0$. Then $$\lim_{j \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\log |f(r_{j}e^{i\theta})|\, d\theta \geq \log |f(0)|.$$ If I could interchange limit and integral then $$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\log |f(e^{i\theta})|\, d\theta \geq \log |f(0)|.$$ If $\{\theta \in [0, 2\pi]: f(e^{i\theta}) = 0\}$ had positive measure, then the left hand side is $-\infty$ while the right hand side is finite, a contradiction. However, I don't know how to justify interchanging the limit and integral.

Comment: You can assume that $|f|\le 1$, so that $\ln |f|\le 0$. Now you can multiply through by $-1$, and Fatou's Lemma will see you home.

Comment: @Christian Remling, Why can one assume that $|f| \leq 1$?

Comment: $f$ is bounded, so consider $cf$ for suitable small $c>0$.